# Pressing a key on the keyboard is opening up an unwanted My Computer window

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard

My USB keyboard, which is Logitech brand, causes a "My Computer" window to open whenever a key is pressed, regardless of which button is pressed. It doesn't open up more than one "My Computer" window. This does not happen in MS Word, but it does happen in a game.  I auto installed the driver software for it without a disc. It never fails to happen.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Could it be a driver issue or a keyboard set up issue or maybe another problem?

Comment: Fair point, OS is windows xp. The software was just an automatic device installation, without a disc. The keyboard properties has identified the device as a HID keyboard. The hardware, I do not know the exact make of it but it is a logitech keyboard. I tested it and it can type fine when I am in microsoft word but when I am in a game it makes the "my computer" window open up regardless of which button I push. Do you have any ideas on whether it is a driver issue or a keyboard set up issue or could it be another problem? Please do advise on if additional information is required.

Comment: Not sure what would cause this, but here are more questions: Is this happening in every game or just one game?  Is MS Word the only way to make it work, or does it work as long as you are not in a game?  Is there any gum in the keyboard causing a key to stick?  Have you tried with another keyboard?  Is there any special software from Logitech installed or is it just standard Windows XP software only?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your keyboard is misconfigured and/or malfunctioning. Go to Control Panel and under Regional Settings and Languages, check your keyboard layout, make sure that it is correct.

Change it to something else and then change it back, just to be sure and then restart. For whatever reason this is a problem sometimes.

If all fails, then see if you can install the right drivers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I am considering searching for the right drivers now as I didnt have much luck with the regional settings. Could you have a look at my additional comment on the question to see if that helps you diagnose the problem further?  I would upvote but I am lacking the rep